# New to Python - learning if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar

I would like to try and print Calendar in Matrix format for the whole year using the calendar.monthcalendar function
I'm trying to see if there is a way of incorporating either an if or a while loop so I don't have to run the code 12 times with a different month variable on the end?

So far I ran the below with a different variable to achieve the end result.

```
print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,1))
```

I would like the end result to be a matrix of an entire year like below.

```
 [[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22], [23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [27, 28, 29, 30, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28], [29, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21,22, 23, 24, 25], [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22], [23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop. In each iteration of the loop, the `calendar.monthcalendar()` function is called. The `range()` function assigns values to x, from 1 to 12 (13 excluded). Therefore x=1 to x=12 is placed into the `calendar.monthcalendar()` function 12 times.

```
for x in range(1,13):
    print(calendar.monthcalendar(2020,x))
```

I would suggest a tutorial, book, or any learning resource because these are the basics of any language you need to grasp before actually starting programming.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a little more info on why this would answer the question.